# Including non referenced projects in publishing profile

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, msbuild

We have a pluggable architecture using MEF that allows us to drop dlls into the bin and then they are loaded by our applications.  We are now starting to move towards automating deployments using the pubxml profiles and different configurations.  The issue we are having is copying the output of non referenced assemblies to the deployment.

In development we are using copy/xcopy to get the dlls and folders to the right bins depending on the configuration but how can we do this using the pubxml files in the publishing profile.  Should we just copy the output directory of the project in question or is there a way using the msbuild commands to tell it to also build a project and include?

Our current pubxml looks like this, it deletes all the ckeditor files, does the deployment and copies them back in afterwards, the CONFIGNAME is the name of the build configuration and this builds other projects in the solution which xcopy the output to the right bin folders so the applications pick them up, as I said this works great in visual studio when debugging but not for publishing.

```
 <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <SourceDirectory>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\..</SourceDirectory>
    <DestinationDirectory>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\..\..\..\..\Deployments\CONFIGNAME</DestinationDirectory>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">

    <Message Text="Delete all files - $(DestinationDirectory)" />

    <ItemGroup>
      <FilesToDelete Include="$(DestinationDirectory)\**\*"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Delete Files="@(FilesToDelete)" />
  </Target>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>CONFIGNAME</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>$(DestinationDirectory)</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="AfterBuild" AfterTargets="MSDeployPublish">
    <CreateItem Include="$(SourceDirectory)\ckeditor\**\*.*">
      <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="CkEditorFiles" />
    </CreateItem>

    <Message Text="Destination directory Name - $(DestinationDirectory)" />
    <Message Text="Source directory Name - $(SourceDirectory)" />

    <Copy SourceFiles="@(CkEditorFiles)"
        DestinationFiles="@(CkEditorFiles->'$(DestinationDirectory)\ckeditor\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?